# How to search and print the details

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a below details in table with some server details

```
Name , Age , DB 
Ali  , 24  , (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX) (HOST = abc.com.xxx) (PORT = 5555)) (SERVER_NAME = xyzui) )  
Bob  , 20  , (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX) (HOST = xyz.com.xxx) (PORT = 5555)) (SERVER_NAME = avhyi) )  
Cin  , 22  ,(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX) (HOST = tyu.com.xxx) (PORT = 5555)) (SERVER_NAME = yuiop) )
```

**I want in below format the output**

```
NAME, AGE , HOST , SERVER_NAME 
Ali , 24  , abc.com.xxx , xyzui
Bob , 20  , xyz.com.xxx , avhyi
Cin , 22  , tyu.com.xxx , yuiop
```

Normal sql query will not give above expected output. I tried to use `CATSEARCH` but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (fast) simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT name,
       age,
       SUBSTR(db, host_pos, INSTR(db, ')', host_pos) - host_pos) AS host,
       SUBSTR(db, port_pos, INSTR(db, ')', port_pos) - port_pos) AS port,
       SUBSTR(db, server_pos, INSTR(db, ')', server_pos) - server_pos) AS server_name
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         age,
         db,
         INSTR(db, '(HOST = ') + 8 AS host_pos,
         INSTR(db, '(PORT = ') + 8 AS port_pos,
         INSTR(db, '(SERVER_NAME = ') + 15 AS server_pos
  FROM   table_name
);
```

or (slower, but less to type) `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT name,
       age,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(db, '\(HOST\s*=\s*(.*?)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS host,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(db, '\(PORT\s*=\s*(.*?)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS port,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(db, '\(SERVER_NAME\s*=\s*(.*?)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS server_name
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Age, DB) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 24, '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX) (HOST = abc.com.xxx) (PORT = 5555)) (SERVER_NAME = xyzui) )' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Bobbi', 20, '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX) (HOST = xyz.com.xxx) (PORT = 5555)) (SERVER_NAME = avhyi) )' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Cindy', 22, '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = XXX) (HOST = tyu.com.xxx) (PORT = 5555)) (SERVER_NAME = yuiop) )' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | NAME | AGE | HOST | PORT | SERVER_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Alice | 24 | abc.com.xxx | 5555 | xyzui |
> | Bobbi | 20 | xyz.com.xxx | 5555 | avhyi |
> | Cindy | 22 | tyu.com.xxx | 5555 | yuiop |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3cac94585ef96a6247d29c35bc667e8a)*